# How do I tether with an HTC Desire on Swisscom?

Tags: htc-desire, tethering

How do I do tethering with an HTC Desire on the Swiss carrier Swisscom? When I plug the phone and pick share internet, my computer asks me for phone number, username and password; oh, and it says I plugged in a modem.

Comment: How are you trying to tether? Are you using PDAnet?

Comment: I just plugged it in and choose "Share internet".

Answer (score 1):

Are the correct drivers for your Desire installed on the laptop? I'm using Windows 7 and with the correct (64 bit) drivers installed, it just connects to the Desire and sees it as a connected network adapter.

Comment: I wasn't aware it needed *drivers*. I thought USB network interfaces were all the same, like USB mice, that you plug and it just works.